# How to strip values in a csv using python with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a small project of extracting data from Cisco ISE. The raw data have attributes that are way more than I needed. So I extracted the file to fewer attributes with codes below.

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
import csv
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('profiler_endpoints.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[["MACAddress","ip","host-name","operating-system","UpdateTime"]]
df['UpdateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UpdateTime'])
df.to_excel("profiler_endpoints_trimmed3.xlsx")
```

[Extracted Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEglA.png)

The extracted table is at the link above. I have trouble filtering the data using date & time since the value of the *UpdateTime* in the column is in *2021-04-15 11:46:44+0800*  format and it shows error **dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: day is out of range for month: 0** when I try to convert the value to date format with code below

`df['UpdateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UpdateTime'])`

Is there any way that I convert the value to date or trim the value from *2021-04-15 11:46:44+0800* to *2021-04-15* so this way I believe it will have no problem to use `pd.to_datetime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# First make the dataframe (just the time column)
data = {'UpdateTime': [
    '2020-12-16 01:10:09+0800',
    '2020-12-16 01:10:09+0800',
    '2020-05-28 01:56:56+0800',
    '2020-09-27 09:47:42+0800',
    '2020-05-28 01:56:56+0800',
    '2020-02-18 10:01:56+0800',
    ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# now convert to datetime
df['UpdateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['UpdateTime'].str.split(' ',1).str[0])

# now double check that in fact we have a datetime
df.info()

out: 
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   UpdateTime  6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
```

Note that `dtypes` above is datetime64. You're done!

Comment: This method works for my script. It basically use some regex filtering to remove the unnecessary value after the date.